# Border CornerRadius странное поведение

Tags: wpf, .net, xaml

Разметка:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Background="White" Width="170" Height="40" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="0,0,10,10" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Panel.ZIndex="1">
            <Border CornerRadius="0,0,10,10" Background="Black"/>
        </Border>
</Grid>
```

Отображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить, слева дочерний `Border` не плотно прилегает к краю доступного пространства. При этом, не смотря на то что родительский `Border` имеет непрозрачный фон, оставшееся место почему то оказывается прозрачным. Есть идеи как это исправить и в чём причина?

Comment: Не смог [воспроизвести](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Md2.png) с указанной разметкой.

Comment: Добавьте в родительский `Grid`:  `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions><ColumnDefinition Width="*"/></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>`.

Comment: Видимо это влияет. По прежнему странно.

Comment: С сеткой аналогично, воспроизвести не смог. Каких-либо отступов я не вижу (кроме закругления, но это уже особенности закругления). У вас будто есть глобальный стиль, который дает бордеру такой отступ. Не знаю, попробуйте через инспектор проанализировать какое свойство за это хотяб влияет, и почему оно там такое. Чистый проект не может иметь отступов, особенно, с одной стороны, со всех сразу (отступ, обводка, и прочее) да, но не с одной...

Comment: Совершенно новый проект создал: https://ibb.co/fMtjDBW. Попробуйте добавить 2 или 3 `ColumnDefinition`, вместо 1.

Comment: Да хоть 10. Как, по-вашему, это должно вдруг добавить отступ внутреннему `Boderd`'у, да еще и с одной стороны? Ну вот просто, давайте подумаем логически, какая связь? Я вашу разметку даже на .NET Framework проекте проверил, и там тоже "чисто". Так что "Не воспроизводится" все еще в силе. Ищите проблему с вашей стороны, может не знаю, у вас OS так упрощенно рендерит XAML, может еще что, но такого быть не должно. XAML не будет добавлять отступы там, где вы его не просите об этом.

Comment: Это понятно, что такого не должно быть по логике вещей. Вопрос в том, почему так происходит. Я использую VS 2022, .NET Framework 4.5